# Graphics context not drawing shapes / not visible

Tags: java, javafx

When running the following code, produces just a blank window as in no visible circles are being drawn. It is expected to produce randomly placed black circles on the window.

Here is my code:

```
package circles;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Circles extends Application {

    private Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400, 400);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Draw Circles");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void drawCircles() {
        // radius of the circles
        final int RADIUS = 20;
        Random rand = new Random();
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        gc.setFill(Color.WHITESMOKE);
        for (int i =0; i <50;i++) {
            int x = rand.nextInt(400);
            int y = rand.nextInt(400);
            gc.fillOval(x,  y, RADIUS, RADIUS);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Circles x = new Circles();
     x.drawCircles();
     launch(args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you call your method `drawCircles()` ?

Comment: Sorry realised I uploaded the wrong version, even with this change it still doesn't work (see above).

Comment: You're calling `drawCircles()` on a different object to the one that is used to create the UI (i.e. a different object than `start()` is called on). Just call `drawCircles()` directly from `start()`.

Comment: Thank you :), sorry seems so obvious now

Answer (score 2):

The [`Application.launch(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-) method creates an instance of the application class, and (after some other work) calls `start()` on it.

In your code, you first create an instance of your application class `Circles`, call `drawCircles()` on it, and then you call `Application.launch(...)`. This causes a second instance of `Circles` to be created, and `start()` to be invoked on that second instance.

Consequently, `drawCircles()` is not called on the same object as `start()`, and so the circles are drawn on a canvas that is never displayed.

Simply move the call to `drawCircles()` to the `start()` method:

```
package circles;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.Random;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Circles extends Application {

    private Canvas canvas = new Canvas(400, 400);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);

        drawCircles();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Draw Circles");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void drawCircles() {
        // radius of the circles
        final int RADIUS = 20;
        Random rand = new Random();
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        gc.setFill(Color.WHITESMOKE);
        for (int i =0; i <50;i++) {
            int x = rand.nextInt(400);
            int y = rand.nextInt(400);
            gc.fillOval(x,  y, RADIUS, RADIUS);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
  }
}
```